# How can I detect a specific 3d model collision three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, collision

I am trying to make clickable 3d objects with Leap Motion. I have two 3D models, IronMan helmet and a Hammer of Thor. If one of those two object is selected, then will change color. For the Iron Man will be green and for the Hammer will be white. But when I am selecting the Hammer, it changes to green instead of white. I use a cube as a pointer to select the object. Can you help?

This is the code to insert 3d models:

```
var colladaMeshlist = []; 
model = new THREE.Object3D()
var object;
var skin;
var objectScale = 1.5;
rotX=0, rotY=0, rotZ=0;
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load( 'models/IronMan.dae', function (collada) {
    object = collada.scene;

    object.scale.x = object.scale.y = object.scale.z = objectScale;

    object.position.x= 20;
    object.position.y= -40;
    object.position.z= 0;

    object.rotation.x= rotX;
    object.rotation.y= rotY;
    object.rotation.z= rotZ;

    object.name="IronMan";      
    colladaMeshlist.push(object);
    model.add(object);

});
scene.add(model);

model2 = new THREE.Object3D()
var object2;
var skin2;
var objectScale2 = 1;
posX=0, posY=-40, posZ=0;
rotX=0, rotY=0, rotZ=0;
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load( 'models/Hammer.dae', function (collada) {
    object2 = collada.scene;

    object2.scale.x = object2.scale.y = object2.scale.z = objectScale2;

    object2.position.x= -20;
    object2.position.y= -20;
    object2.position.z= posZ;

    object2.rotation.x= rotX;
    object2.rotation.y= rotY;
    object2.rotation.z= rotZ;
    object2.name="Hammer";  
    colladaMeshlist.push(object2);
    model2.add(object2);
});
scene.add(model2);
```

This is the code for selecting the objects:

```
      var originPoint = cube.position.clone();
      for(var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < cube.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
       {
           var localVertex = cube.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
           var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( cube.matrix );
           var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( cube.position );
           var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
           var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects(colladaMeshlist, true);

           if(collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length())  
          {
             collisionResults[0].object.material.color.setHex(0x4CAF50);
          } 
          else if (collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[1].distance < directionVector.length())
          {
             collisionResults[1].object.material.color.setHex(0xffffff);
          }
  }
```

Comment: your code do not have a condition to decide which selected object has to be colored in white or green. I only read that the first object has to be green if it is inside the cube, which applies to your hammer+helmet. Also the `else if` seems strange to me : you've written : if the first object is in the cube (...) else if the second object is in the cube ? How could a first object not intersect the cube but the second yes (`intersectObjects` returns an array sorted by distance) ?

Comment: Unless i missed something in this previous comment, you could do like this : 1. only keep the first `if` block ; 2. just check what the object's name is into this block : `if(collisionResult[0].object.name==='IronMan')`>color in green. Same with white for the hammer.

Comment: I have used your solution, but is it still not working. At the models I have 'code' object.name === "IronMan". With colladaMeshlist[0].name I get the object name, but it is still notworking.

Comment: At the models you have = not ===.

Comment: I have found the solution